# Inconsistent BufferWithTime Behavior

Tags: unit-testing, system.reactive

I have a unit test that tests BufferWithTime. I seem to be getting inconsistent results when values are emitted at the point the buffering will emit a new value.

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

var source = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
    new Recorded<Notification<int>>(50, new Notification<int>.OnNext(1)),
    new Recorded<Notification<int>>(100, new Notification<int>.OnNext(2)),
    new Recorded<Notification<int>>(150, new Notification<int>.OnNext(3)),
    new Recorded<Notification<int>>(200, new Notification<int>.OnNext(4)),
    new Recorded<Notification<int>>(250, new Notification<int>.OnNext(5)),
    new Recorded<Notification<int>>(300, new Notification<int>.OnNext(6)),
    new Recorded<Notification<int>>(350, new Notification<int>.OnNext(7)),
    new Recorded<Notification<int>>(400, new Notification<int>.OnNext(8)),
    new Recorded<Notification<int>>(450, new Notification<int>.OnNext(9)),
    new Recorded<Notification<int>>(450, new Notification<int>.OnCompleted()));

var results = scheduler.Run(() => source
    .BufferWithTime(TimeSpan.FromTicks(150), scheduler));
```

The results I get back from this are essentially:

```
results[0] = [1,2]
results[1] = [3,4,5,6]
results[2] = [7,8,9]
```

My question is, why is there only two items in the first buffer and 4 in the second?  I would expect that a source that emits at the same time as buffering is supposed to happen, they either always go in the buffer or are always queued for the next buffer. Have I just stumbled upon a bug?

Comment: Sounds like it's probably related to the way TestScheduler schedules "immediate" actions to be 1-tick future actions. Might want to ask on the forums - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on responses on the MSDN forums this isn't a bug. You can read their answers [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/de4e6152-5d28-4bb5-bc49-7331b3f05ac4/).

Basically, when something is scheduled to execute at exactly the same time as something else, it's the order of scheduling that takes precedence i.e. they are queued. When looking at the ordering of the scheduling with the above example you can see why I'm getting the behaviour that I'm getting.

1. BufferWithTime schedules a window to
   open at 0 and close at 150.
2. The cold Source is then subscribed
   to which schedules **all** other
   notifications. At this point, the value to be
   emitted at 150 is then queued behind
   the closing of the window.
3. At time 150 the window closes first
   (emitting the first buffer of two
   values). The next window is opened
   and is scheduled to close at 300.
   The value that is scheduled to be
   emitted at 150 is added to the
   second buffer.
4. At time 300, the value 6 was
   scheduled to be emitted first (as it
   was scheduled when the source was
   subscribed to) so it is added to the
   second buffer. BufferWithTime then closes the window (emits the buffer) and opens a new one scheduled to close at 450.

They cycle will then continue consistently.